# Magento 2.2.4 Web Setup Wizard blank page

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento2.2.4, web-setup-wizard

I need your help please...
After upgrade from 2.2.3 to 2.2.4 I got blank page when I click on Web Setup Wizard in System>Tools> Web Setup Wizard.
It was working before upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the Solution in my case

Go to public_html/app/etc/env.php and change the following code from

```
'session' => [
'save' => 'db'
```

to

```
'session' => [
'save' => 'files'
```